# The determinant as a differential operator

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-operators, determinants, hyperbolic-pde

According to Gårding, the determinant is a **hyperbolic polynomial** over the space $\mathbf{Sym}_n$ of real symmetric $n\times n$ matrices. More precisely, it is hyperbolic in the direction of the identity matrix $I_n$, or more generally of any positive definite matrix $P$.

Gårding's statement means that the differential operator
$$L:=\det\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial a_{ij}}\right),$$
where $a_{ij}\equiv a_{ji}$, is hyperbolic. In other words, the Cauchy problem $Lf(A)=0$, with initial data given on the hyperplane $\operatorname{Tr} A=0$ (for instance), is well-posed.

My question is whether this differential operator occurs somewhere, apart from Gårding's work. If $n=2$, $L$ is equivalent to the wave operator in $3$ variables (two space dimensions). But in general, $L$ has order $n$. Mind that an initial condition consists of $n$ arbitrary functions on the initial hyperplane.

**Edit**. As [commented](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461818/the-determinant-as-a-differential-operator#comment1198024_461818) by Mariano, $L$ is the restriction to $\mathbf{Sym}_n$ of Cayley's $\Omega$ process. However this does not answer my question, because $\Omega$ is not hyperbolic. The hyperbolicity makes $L$ somewhat specific in the context of differential operators.

Comment: That's Cayley's $\Omega$ process restricted to symmetric matrices, no? It appearts in Capelli's identites, for example, and in the proof that certain invariant rings are finitely generated.

Comment: Gårding, not Gaarding, right? Could you give a specific reference for the claim? (A quick search turned up [MR0196280](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=196280); is that it?)

Comment: @LSpice could you provide a ZBmath link instead of something behind an expensive paywall?

Comment: @YCor, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461818/the-determinant-as-a-differential-operator#comment1198111_461818), MR article references (as opposed to reviews) are free to view, and I find ZBmath clunky to navigate so prefer not to, especially without even knowing if that's the right article.  But of course you are welcome to add any links that you find helpful.

Comment: @LSpice but your link provides me with a paywall, with no reference info at all.

Comment: @YCor, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1198136), yes, sorry, I just checked and you are right.  Certainly it used to work that way, so either they changed it or I formatted the link incorrectly.  The article is [Gårding, Kotake, and Leray -
Uniformisation et développement asymptotique de la solution du problème de Cauchy linéaire, à données holomorphes ; analogie avec la théorie des ondes asymptotiques et approchées (Problème de Cauchy I bis et VI.)](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=BSMF_1964__92__263_0).

Comment: @LSpice My references are 1) L. Gårding, Linear hyperbolic partial differential equations with constant coefficients. *Acta Math.*, **85** (1951), p 1-62 and 2) An inequality for hyperbolic polynomials. *J. Math. Mech.*, **8** (1959), p 957-965.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gårding's differential operator (introduced in [Extension of a Formula by Cayley to Symmetric Determinants](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0013091500024810)) is discussed by Turnbull in [Symmetric Determinants and the Cayley and Capelli Operator](https://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0013091500024822):

> The result obtained by Lars Gårding, who uses the Cayley operator upon
> a symmetric matrix, is of considerable interest ... it is significant
> to have learnt from Professor A. C. Aitken in March this year 1946,
> that he too was finding the symmetrical matrix operator of importance
> and has already written on the matter.

[For Aitken's work, see [A Note on Trace-Differentiation and the $\Omega$-operator](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0013091500014152)]

Turnbull also considers the case where the matrix is skew-symmetric, rather than symmetric. An overview of the literature is given in [Algebraic/combinatorial proofs of Cayley-type identities for derivatives of determinants and pfaffians](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.aam.2012.12.001).

Gårding's [theory of hyperbolic polynomials](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24900665) is the topic of [Hyperbolic polynomials and the Dirichlet problem](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.5220). The name "Dirichlet-Gårding polynomial" is used for this general class.

Other references on this topic include

- [Roots of Gårding hyperbolic polynomials](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.01077) (2020)
- [Van der Waerden/Schrijver-Valiant like Conjectures and Stable (aka Hyperbolic) Homogeneous Polynomials : One Theorem for all](https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.3496) (2007)
- [The Lax conjecture is true](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0304104) (2003)
- [Hyperbolic Polynomials and Convex Analysis](https://people.orie.cornell.edu/aslewis/publications/01-hyperbolic.pdf) (2001)